# angularJS textarea - textarea not showing text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this textarea

```
<textarea ng-model="textArea" ng-change="update(data.id,textArea)" style="height:120px; width:200px;">{{data.description}}</textarea>
```

when i run it the html code is:

```
<textarea ng-model="textArea" ng-change="update(data.id,textArea)" style="height:120px; width:200px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-binding">my test 123</textarea>
```

nothing strange except that i don't see the text on the textarea in the page.....
some ideas??

Comment: i tried also adding a name tag and id but nothing change....and using static text noting change....=/

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. The current value of textarea comes from databinding (**ng-model**).

```
<textarea ng-model="textArea" ng-change="update(data.id,texArea)" 
       style="height:120px; width:200px;"></textarea>
```

in your controller, use `$scope.textArea = 'YOURVALUE';`

Alternatively you can set up "double binding" in controller, such as:

```
$scope.$watch('data.description', function(newValue){
  $scope.textArea = newValue;
});
```

ps, you have TYPO whe trying to spell "**textArea**", you've spelt it as "**texArea**".